# How to Change the text of DATABOUND TEXTBOX in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, formview, databound

I want to change the text of databound textbox inside a formview and show the change inline in textbox(not just do this in behind with FIND CONTROL and TextBox Class).
All i Know is Until This :

```
 TextBox TxtNew = (TextBox)FormViewbla.FindControl("Txt_blabla");
 TxtNew.Text = "some bla";
```

NOW how can i put TxtNew text in my Txt_blabla TextBox in FormView?

Comment: how about Txt_blabla=TxtNew.Text ??

Comment: Not Answered...... :( And you can not access to Txt_blabla like this.....Just the way is FindControl method

Comment: possibly I'm not getting the point if you can find one text box using FindControl then why not the second? Better you show us your code for better picture.

Comment: You CaN jUST TRY yourself Code AS Txt_blabla=TxtNew.Text ??>>>>Is it Compile and working...make diffrence in databound textbox.text?

it's not...So this is the code my friend....I Told you...Very Simple to ask but hard to answer....How can you Get a DataBoundTextBox.Text,Change it,and do the change in DataBoundTextBox.Text

Comment: Change the data in the data source and bind it again

Comment: googd trick...but not his answer Gian Acuna